# Streaming HTML from Java web application

Tags: java, html, streaming

How to achieve continuous HTML streaming in a Java web application?

Like, making the page keep on loading (indicates) and push data from server.

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax you can call the server continuously and continue to refresh parts of the page.

Obviously you would be better using timeouts and not continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you're talking about doing content replacement (multipart/replace) or doing Comet-style push you can look at http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartResponse.html (for multipart replacement: some IP cameras use similar techniques to do crude video) or look at things like http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html or http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3 for Comet streaming.